# Best handling for problems detected inside of the reactjs render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

O wrote a very primitive sort of router simply getting the `componentName` from the `props`.

```
export class RoutingComp extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {
        const {componentName, ...rest} = this.props;
        let comp = NAME_TO_COMPONENT_MAP[componentName];
        if (!comp) {
            setComponentName('DefaultComponent');
            console.warn("Unknown component", name);
            return null;
        }
        return React.createElement(comp, rest);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except when an illegal `componentName` is given. Then I show nothing and call `setComponentName` which called `setState` in some parent component. Then my `RoutingComp` is re-rendered and the problem is fixed, except for that I get the well-known warning:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I do understand the problem, and how it could lead to problems, including an [endless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42745415/581205) (which can't happen in my case), but I can't see any *nice* solution.

- Using `componentWillMount` doesn't make sense as `componentName` could change anytime.
- Using `componentDidUpdate` seems to lead to the very same warning and possibly the same endless loop.
- Using a different component for fixing the `componentName` leads to code repetitions, possibly risking getting out of sync.
- The same holds for making it a responsibility of the reducer.
- Showing the default component and ignoring the wrong `componentName` feels dirty.
- Ignoring the problem and hoping that it never happens feels even worse.

I've read tens of answers concerning the warning, but they didn't help me with choosing the proper solution. Feel free to close my question as duplicate if you see a clear and founded answer.

Comment: What about [`error boundaries`](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)?

Comment: @TheReason I've tried them once (a week ago) and they didn't work at all. As I didn't really need them, I gave up for now.