# How to set the state inside map function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the code snippet as below:

**state variables:**

```
state = {
  value: 'default value', 
  items: [{id: 1, title: 't1'}, {id: 2, title: 't2'}]
}
```

**inside render function:**

```
this.state.items.map((data, key) => (

  // I want to set the state of 'value' here something like this
  this.setState({ value: 'somevalue' })

))
```

I want to map through the array and check for a particular `id` in the array say, if the array contains an `id = 1`, then set the state `value` as `t1`, similarly, if an array contains an `id = 2`, then set the state of `value` as `t2`.

Inside `map` function, we can't set the state repeatedly. What would be the alternative for this?

Comment: For example: data=['id:1,'title':'this is a first value,'id:2,'title':'this is a second value]. I have a state variable called as newVariable set to 0. Now, I want to map through the array and check for particular string in the array say, if array contains  a string 'first' then set the state varaible newVariable as first, similarly, if an array contains a string 'second' then set the state of newVariable as second. I want to achieve something like this.

Comment: As @AjeetShah mentions, calling `setState()` inside the `render()` doesn't seem to be right... Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677229/how-to-not-use-setstate-inside-render-function-in-react

Comment: You can use forEach instead of map, but as already mentioned, it doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to (and should not) set a state inside any loop.

In this example, you simply need to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the matching item and, if found, set its value in the state, as shown below:

```js
const { Component } = React

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      value: 'default value', 
      items: [{id: 1, title: 't1'}, {id: 2, title: 't2'}]
    }
  }
  
  handleClick = (id) => {
    const found = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === id)
    if (found) {
      this.setState({value: found.title})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        value: {this.state.value} <br/>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>Click (1)</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>Click (2)</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```