# How can I fix this error Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, callback, render, ternary

I get this error:

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
> `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
> state.

And it happens in this code at `callback(newDisplayName)`

I know why it happens that a `render` should not be triggerd like my callback is doing! And I try to solve it but I'm confused .
I read this [cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-error-in-react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745176/cannot-update-during-an-existing-state-transition-error-in-react)

But I cant get it to work as suggest like I should use some lambda like:

```
{(newDisplayName) =>  callback(newDisplayName) }`
```

But I have a ternary operation so it's not the same right? I maybe dont have to make the callback in the render but I get this Redux `mapStateToProps` updated that trigger the render so dunno where else to do this

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/change-name.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Dots from 'react-activity/lib/Dots';
import 'react-activity/lib/Dots/Dots.css';
import { changeDisplayName } from '../../redux/userData/user.actions';

class ChangeName extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { authUser } = this.props;
        this.state = {
            displayName: authUser.displayName ?? '',
        };
    }

    onSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.updateUserName();
    };

    onChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    updateUserName() {
        const { displayName } = this.state;
        const { changeUserDisplayName } = this.props;
        changeUserDisplayName(displayName.trim());
    }

    render() {
        const { displayName } = this.state;
        const { callback } = this.props;
        const { authUser, savingDisplayName, newDisplayName, changeDisplayNameErr } = this.props;
        const isInvalid = !displayName || !displayName.trim() || displayName.trim().length > 20;
        const isAmended = displayName && displayName.trim() !== authUser.displayName;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="changename">
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <input
                            name="displayName"
                            value={displayName}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            type="text"
                            maxLength="20"
                            placeholder="Display name"
                        />
                        <button className="changenamebutton" disabled={isInvalid || !isAmended} type="submit">
                            Confirm
                        </button>
                        {isInvalid && <p className="error">Display name must be between 1 and 20 characters in length</p>}
                        {changeDisplayNameErr && <p className="error">{changeDisplayNameErr.message}</p>}
                        {newDisplayName && <p className="error">New name was saved!</p>}
                        {newDisplayName ? callback(newDisplayName) : ''}
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>{savingDisplayName ? <Dots /> : null}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    changeUserDisplayName: displayName => dispatch(changeDisplayName(displayName)),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        savingDisplayName: state.user.isSavingDisplayName,
        newDisplayName: state.user.displayName,
        changeDisplayNameErr: state.user.changeDisplayNameErrMsg,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChangeName);
```

Here is the mother Component for the callback:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/profile-page-anonymous.css';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withFirebase } from '../../firebase';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization } from '../../session';
import ChangeName from './ChangeName';
import * as ROLES from '../../constants/roles';

class ProfilePageBase extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            displayName: props.authUser.displayName ?? '',
        };
        this.nameChange = this.nameChange.bind(this);
    }

    nameChange(displayName) {
        this.setState({
            displayName,
        });
    }

    render() {
        let userDetails;
        const { authUser } = this.props;
        const { displayName } = this.state;
        if (authUser) {
            userDetails = (
                <div>
                    <div className="profileAnonymous">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Display name: </td>
                                    <td>{displayName}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User ID: </td>
                                    <td>{authUser.uid}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Anonymous: </td>
                                    <td>{authUser.isAnonymous ? 'True' : 'False'}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Change your display name</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="profileBoxChangeNameAnonymous">
                        <ChangeName authUser={authUser} callback={this.nameChange} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            userDetails = <p>Unable to get user details. Please try refreshing the page.</p>;
        }

        return <div>{userDetails}</div>;
    }
}

const ProfilePageAnon = props => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (
            <div className="profilePageAnonymous">
                <ProfilePageBase {...props} authUser={authUser} />
            </div>
        )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => authUser && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON);

const enhance = compose(withAuthorization(condition), withFirebase);
const ProfilePageAnonymous = enhance(ProfilePageAnon);

export default ProfilePageAnonymous;
```

**UPDATE**

Refactoring `ProfilePageBase` to solve the problem! Thanks to @DrewReese. I learn about the anti-pattern to not store passed props in component state. now I refactor the `ProfilePageBase` into a stateless component.

`ProfilePageBase` is a `<AuthUserContext.Consumer>` that listening to Firestore changes on the user object so when `ChangName` save the new name to Firestore then `ProfilePageBase` Consume the `AuthUserContext` HOC render `value` that is the user object having the new name. So now `ChangName` don't need to think/know about `callback`

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/profile-page-anonymous.css';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withFirebase } from '../../firebase';
import { AuthUserContext, withAuthorization } from '../../session';
import ChangeName from './ChangeName';
import * as ROLES from '../../constants/roles';

function ProfilePageBase({ authUser }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {authUser ? (
                <div>
                    <div className="profileAnonymous">
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Display name: </td>
                                    <td>{authUser.displayName}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>User ID: </td>
                                    <td>{authUser.uid}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Anonymous: </td>
                                    <td>{authUser.isAnonymous ? 'True' : 'False'}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Change your display name</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="profileBoxChangeNameAnonymous">
                        <ChangeName authUser={authUser} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p>Unable to get user details. Please try refreshing the page.</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

const ProfilePageAnon = props => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser => (
            <div className="profilePageAnonymous">
                <ProfilePageBase {...props} authUser={authUser} />
            </div>
        )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
);

const condition = authUser => authUser && authUser.roles.includes(ROLES.ANON);

const enhance = compose(withAuthorization(condition), withFirebase);
const ProfilePageAnonymous = enhance(ProfilePageAnon);

export default ProfilePageAnonymous;
```

Comment: What is `props.callback`? What does it do? The render methods ***should*** be pure functions, which means they shouldn't call any functions that create side-effects.

Comment: `props.callback` is a callback to mother component. Yes I know render should be pure that's why I ask this question how to fix that

Comment: Ok. What have you done to not update a state value somewhere during a render? Looks like `callback` is possibly doing something to `newDisplayName` prop passed in from redux. What does `callback(newDisplayName)` do?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese I added code to show what mother Component do, it's very simple callback but it `setState` so it's a problem

Comment: I see that `ChangeName` is passed `callback={this.nameChange}` which is updating state in the parent. This can't be done from the render of the child. `newDisplayName` appears to to be passed from redux so any local component state updates *should* occur in a lifecycle method. Is there a reason `ProfilePageBase` doesn't subscribe to the store for the `newDisplayName`? Or do you *need* `ChangeName` to call the callback to update state in the parent? Coincidentally, it is also a react anti-pattern to store passed props in component state.

Comment: No there's nothing stopping `ProfilePageBase` to subscribe to the Redux success action result `newDisplayName` from the reducer. Thanks I learn some stuff now, I made it even simpler the `ProfilePageBase` is a `<AuthUserContext.Consumer>` that listening to Firestore changes on the user object so when `ChangName` save the new new name to Firestore then  `ProfilePageBase` Consume the AuthUserContext HOC render `value` that is the user oblej having the new name .

Comment: Thanks I learn about the anti-pattern to not store passed props in component state now. I refactor the `ProfilePageBase` into a function stateless component. updating me code..

Comment: @DrewReese make an answer and I can accept it!

Comment: All I did was ask a bunch of questions and let you know about a react anti-pattern, you did the rest on your own. :p You can answer/resolve your own questions/issues, BTW.